# How to filter User by role based on the called Model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laratrust

I'm using `Laratrust` to manage these roles:

- Patient
- Doctor

I've a class called `User` which is the main entity, then I have a specific class for each role: `Patient` and `Doctor`.

**Problem**

To retrieve a list of users with the role of `doctor` I have to write:

```
User::whereRoleIs('doctor')->get();
```

The problem's that I have defined some relationship within the class `Doctor`, eg:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Boilerplate\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Doctor extends User
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function patients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Patient::class, 'invites', 'doctor_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

and I cannot access to the relationship `patients` from the `User` model.
Is there a way to call `Doctor:with('patients')->get()` and return automatically the users which have the role of `Doctor`?

So if I type: `Doctor:all()` the result must be equal to `User::whereRoleIs('doctor')->get()`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting data like this by model isn't really the intended use for models. Models in Laravel contain data on a per-table basis. In order to achieve what you want I would either make a `DocterService` that has methods in it to retrieve docter users by calling `User::whereRoleIs('doctor')` or just use this method straight away.

If you really want to use the model though you can use scopes. (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes) Create a new scope that includes the `whereRoleIs('doctor')` method

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Scopes;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
 
class DoctorScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->whereRoleIs('doctor');
    }
}
```

and apply it to the model by adding the following to the model:

```
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new DoctorScope);
    }
```

Comment: Do you suggest to remove Doctor and Patient models? If so, should I implement all the relationship in the User model?

Comment: Yes, that's what is considered best practice if I understood the docs etc right.